# Is there any considerations I should take when running untrusted apps as non-root user?

Tags: files, security, process

I have to use an application I don't trust (unstable) and I will run it as a non-privileged user so if something bad happens the damage would be limited to the home folder of that user.

- I removed the setuid and setgid bit from all files under that user.
- The files are owned by the user and and a group named after the user.
- The only files the user and the group could write are inside the user's home directory.
- The user could read and execute other files like /usr/bin.

Is it safe to said that the damage would be limited to the user's home folder?

Is there any extra consideration I should take to make it safer?

Comment: Are you using a rhel distribution? If so you can use SELinux to further secure the system using its discretionary access control.

Comment: Run your app inside a virtual container. A chroot might be sufficient, but in theory it is possible to break out of a chroot. However, there are virtualizations methods for which it is impossible to break out of.